Метод sent_tokenize библиотеки NLTK отказывается работать
Необходимая библиотека установлена и подключена:
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

Прекрасно работает функция word_tokenize:
text_words = "Hello! How are you?"
words = word_tokenize(text=text_words, preserve_line=True)
print(words)

#['Hello', '!', 'How', 'are', 'you', '?']

А вот как выглядит вывод у sent_tokenize:
text_sents = "Hello! How are you?"
sents = sent_tokenize(text=text_sents, language="english")
print(sents)


> {     "name": "LookupError",  "message": "
> **********************************************************************   Resource punkt_tab not found.   Please use the NLTK Downloader to
> obtain the resource:
> 
>   >>> import nltk
>   >>> nltk.download('punkt_tab')
>      For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html
> 
>   Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt_tab/english/
> 
>   Searched in:
>     - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\bem54/nltk_data'
>     - 'd:\\\\Anaconda\\\\envs\\\\Neiro\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'd:\\\\Anaconda\\\\envs\\\\Neiro\\\\share\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'd:\\\\Anaconda\\\\envs\\\\Neiro\\\\lib\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\bem54\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'D:\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'E:\\\ ltk_data'
> ********************************************************************** ",     "stack":
> "--------------------------------------------------------------------------- LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[87], line 2
>       1 text_sents = \"Hello! How are you?\"
> ----> 2 sents = sent_tokenize(text=text_sents, language=\"english\")
>       3 print(sents)
> 
> File d:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Neiro\\Lib\\site-packages\
> ltk\\tokenize\\__init__.py:119, in sent_tokenize(text, language)
>     109 def sent_tokenize(text, language=\"english\"):
>     110     \"\"\"
>     111     Return a sentence-tokenized copy of *text*,
>     112     using NLTK's recommended sentence tokenizer    (...)
>     117     :param language: the model name in the Punkt corpus
>     118     \"\"\"
> --> 119     tokenizer = _get_punkt_tokenizer(language)
>     120     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
> 
> File d:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Neiro\\Lib\\site-packages\
> ltk\\tokenize\\__init__.py:105, in _get_punkt_tokenizer(language)
>      96 @functools.lru_cache
>      97 def _get_punkt_tokenizer(language=\"english\"):
>      98     \"\"\"
>      99     A constructor for the PunktTokenizer that utilizes
>     100     a lru cache for performance.    (...)
>     103     :type language: str
>     104     \"\"\"
> --> 105     return PunktTokenizer(language)
> 
> File d:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Neiro\\Lib\\site-packages\
> ltk\\tokenize\\punkt.py:1744, in PunktTokenizer.__init__(self, lang)  
> 1742 def __init__(self, lang=\"english\"):    1743    
> PunktSentenceTokenizer.__init__(self)
> -> 1744     self.load_lang(lang)
> 
> File d:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Neiro\\Lib\\site-packages\
> ltk\\tokenize\\punkt.py:1749, in PunktTokenizer.load_lang(self, lang) 
> 1746 def load_lang(self, lang=\"english\"):    1747     from nltk.data
> import find
> -> 1749     lang_dir = find(f\"tokenizers/punkt_tab/{lang}/\")    1750     self._params = load_punkt_params(lang_dir)    1751     self._lang =
> lang
> 
> File d:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Neiro\\Lib\\site-packages\ ltk\\data.py:579,
> in find(resource_name, paths)
>     577 sep = \"*\" * 70
>     578 resource_not_found = f\"\ {sep}\ {msg}\ {sep}\ \"
> --> 579 raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
> 
> LookupError: 
> **********************************************************************   Resource punkt_tab not found.   Please use the NLTK Downloader to
> obtain the resource:
> 
>   >>> import nltk
>   >>> nltk.download('punkt_tab')
>      For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html
> 
>   Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt_tab/english/
> 
>   Searched in:
>     - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\bem54/nltk_data'
>     - 'd:\\\\Anaconda\\\\envs\\\\Neiro\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'd:\\\\Anaconda\\\\envs\\\\Neiro\\\\share\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'd:\\\\Anaconda\\\\envs\\\\Neiro\\\\lib\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\bem54\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'D:\\\ ltk_data'
>     - 'E:\\\ ltk_data'
> ********************************************************************** " }

Изображение текста ошибки (может быть выйдет нагляднее)

Также уточню, что использую дистрибутив Anaconda и платформу Jupyter Notebook.

Попробуйте сначала скачать данные: import nltk; nltk.download()

Спасибо за предложение @CrazyElf, но уже скачаны. Просто забыл добавить в текст вопроса. nltk.download("punkt") nltk.download("wordnet")

Надо выставлять тогда вручную видимо путь к данным nltk. Нужно только найти, куда они скачались: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987374/8324991

Решил собственную проблему одним незамысловатым способом, а именно этой строчкой кода:
nltk.download('all')

То есть, скачав все пакеты.
